# How to I filter string with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have variable `payload` which comes from mqtt message.payloadString, I'm appending it like this `$("#sisu").append('<span id="koikpay">' + payload+ '</span>');` Now I have multiple spans. **How can I filter out specific data ?**

I want to filter out `SIGNAL:-55` with javascript, so later I can have a separate SIGNAL:-55. Should I make every new span line with new id ? Or are there any other methods to this ?

**Payload**

```
 var payload= "Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259 "
```

**Result**

```
$("#sisu").append('<span id="koikpay">' + payload+ '</span>');

<span id="koikpay">Online  111:920:9</span>
<span id="koikpay">info  191:220:9</span>
<span id="koikpay">Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:290:9</span>
<span id="koikpay">WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: F9:1A:67:99:19:99, SIGNAL: -55  111:220:9</span>
<span id="koikpay">WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 9C:C9:7F:1F:99:55  111:220:9</span>
<span id="koikpay">IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259</span>
```

Comment: first of all, don't have multiple elements with the same `id` (`id="koikpay"`)

Comment: instead of `id` use `class` like:- `<span class="koikpay">Online  111:920:9</span>...so on for others`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ritwika/mvk8xhz8/

Please follow the code below and use class instead of id for displaying payload as array strings.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var payload = `Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259`;
var array = payload.split(/\n/g);
$.each(array,function(i){
   //alert(array[i]);
   $("#sisu").append('<span class="koikpay">' + array[i] + '</span>');
  if(array[i].includes("SIGNAL")){
    var array1 = array[i].split(/[,]+/);
    $.each(array1,function(i){
      if(array1[i].includes("SIGNAL")){
       //alert(array1[i]);
      var array2 = array1[i].split("  ");
         $.each(array2,function(i){
           if(array2[i].includes("SIGNAL")){
             $("#signal").append('<span class="koikpay" style="color:red;">' + array2[i] + '</span>');
            }
         });
      }
    });
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sisu"></div>
<div id="signal"></div>
```

Comment: hey,I have posted the full code including the signal data to be fetched.Hope this could help you...

Comment: I still have problem, it's not working because payload(var payload = message.payloadString;) is an mqtt.js variable and I cant make it to backticks variable..

Comment: No worryes, I got It working1 :) Thank you for your anwser

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have:

```
var payload= `Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259`;
```

Start with splitting:

```
payload = payload.split("\n").map(s => s.trim())
```

Then iterate again, and extract whichever data you need.

Answer (score 1):

With a template string literals with back ticks "`". You can split it with the new line and then just iterate it to put in the DOM:

```js
var payload = `Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259`;

var arr = payload.split(/\n/g);
arr.forEach((item) => {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="koikpay">' + item + '</span>'
});
```

```css
.koikpay {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Still.. how can I filter out data, like the signal ? Is is possible to change the class for each of the payload, like arr.forEach((item) => {
        sa++;
        ss=ss+sa;
  document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="'+ss+'">' + item + '</span>'
}); Tho this dosent work